# Flow Router param not changing inside hook and subscription

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, flow-router, meteor-tracker

I am using

```
Template.taskList.onCreated( () => {
  var projectId = FlowRouter.getParam( 'projectId' );
  var postHooks = {
    before: {
      insert: function ( doc ) {
        doc.projectId = projectId;
        return doc;
      }
    }
  };

  Template.instance().subscribe( 'tasks', projectId );
  AutoForm.addHooks( 'addTask', postHooks );
} );
```

to add `projectId` to all created tasks and subscribe to tasks with the specified `projectId`.

However, when I change the `projectId` with `FlowRouter.setParam( 'projectId' ... )`, it seems `projectId` is not changing in my hook and subscription.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to put it inside `Tracker.autorun()` or something? Is it because I use `onCreated` instead of `onRendered`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you indeed need to use `autorun`. The reason is that flow router parameters are not a reactive datasource, i.e., a change in their value does not trigger reevaluation of code depending on it.

Comment: How much of the code should be inside autorun? The flow router parameters are reactive when I use populate my template through the helpers, so I do not understand why they are not reactive in this situation.